# JavaScript Uncaught Type Error while computing distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am simply trying to compute distances between two points but it's giving me Uncaught TypeError: a.lat is not a function.

```js
 function MapLocations() {
        
            var i = 0;
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
             var myLatLng = {lat: 31.553761202565646, lng: 74.26506623625755}
                var m = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    clickable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    title: 'My Home',
                    position: myLatLng,
                   // html: h[i],
                    
                });

                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map,
                    radius: 18.288,    // 10 miles in metres
                    fillColor: '#50D050'
                });

                circle.bindTo('center', m, 'position');
                
             var distanceInMetres = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myLatLng, pos).toFixed(2);
             //console.log(distanceInMetres);
                //google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function () {
                //    infoWindow.setContent('Hello');
                //    infoWindow.open(map, this);
                //});
                //google.maps.event.addListener(dragable_marker, 'dragend', function (e) {
                //    alert(circle.getBounds().contains(dragable_marker.getPosition()));
                //});

               //alert(distanceInMetres);
                i++;

            
        }
```

pos is the user position taken from navigator object. The thing is it's all working good while i remove computedistance.

Comment: Are you sure `myLatLng` should be a plain object? It seems as if the library is expect your `lat` property to be a function, not a value

Comment: related question: [Google maps a.lat is not a function.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600543/google-maps-a-lat-is-not-a-function)

Comment: related question: [Google Maps API a.lat is not a function error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640449/google-maps-api-a-lat-is-not-a-function-error)

Answer (score 2):

The [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistancBetween`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#spherical) method doesn't work with [LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngLiteral) objects (at least presently), you have to pass in [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) objects.

from [the (latest) documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#spherical):

> **computeDistanceBetween**(from:**LatLng**, to:**LatLng**, radius?:number)
>
> Return Value:  number
>
> Returns the distance, in meters, between two LatLngs. You can optionally specify a custom radius. The radius defaults to the radius of the Earth.

Answer (score 0):

You have a sintax error. Have a last javascript object attribute with comma

```
           var m = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                clickable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: 'My Home',
                position: myLatLng,
                                 ??? this is wrong
               // html: h[i],

            });
```

you should use it without `,`

```
           var m = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                clickable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: 'My Home',
                position: myLatLng

               // html: h[i],

            });
```

Comment: As i told the problem is just with computeDistanceBetween function