# google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset error (a.lat is not a function)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I wanted a latlng value near a particular distance. I went throught the documentation of google maps api v3.

Have a look at my code :

```
generateCirclepolygon(){
  for (let location of this.pointsLocation) {
    let LatLng:any = {
      lat: parseFloat(location.lat),
      lng: parseFloat(location.lng)
    };
    let newpoints = [];
    var polypoint = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(LatLng , 3000 , 0)
    console.log(polypoint , 'point');
  }
}
```

After runing this code im getting `ERROR TypeError: a.lat is not a function`.

I'm sending a `LatLng` object to that which has `lat` and `lng` values and they are numbers. 3000 is the distance in meters and 0 is heading (i.e 0 degrees in clock wise from north).

I want the latlng value from my point to 3000 meters towards north. My main aim is to draw a circular polygon around a point by repeating this to get an array of points.

Comment: After running this code I get nothing. Because your code is incomplete. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That said why don't you create a Circle then?

Comment: @MrUpsidown  I already created a circle. I want a polygon over that circle on button click. Thanks for commenting but I think Ive found the answer. I need to convert the latlng using

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat , location.lng). 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Related questions:

- [Google maps a.lat is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600543/google-maps-a-lat-is-not-a-function)
- [Google Maps API a.lat is not a function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640449/google-maps-api-a-lat-is-not-a-function-error)

Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/geometry#spherical.computeOffset), the `computeOffset` method takes a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/coordinates#LatLng) as an argument:

> **computeOffset(from, distance, heading[, radius])**
>   **Parameters:**
>  
>   from:  **LatLng**
>   distance:  number
>   heading:  number
>   radius (optional):  number
>   Return Value:  LatLng
>   Returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north).

You are providing a [LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/coordinates#LatLngLiteral) (which doesn't have a `.lat` method, it has a `.lat` property.

```
let LatLng:any = {
  lat: parseFloat(location.lat),
  lng: parseFloat(location.lng)
};
```

should be:

```
let LatLng:any = new google.maps.LatLng(
  parseFloat(location.lat),
  parseFloat(location.lng)
);
```